# How to setup PXE on separate DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp

my network has a DHCP server incapable of serving PXE requests (you cannot set next-server option at all) and thist server MUST remain as DHCP server.

I would like to have a PXE booting on the network, but as I said earlier, I cannot do that with this current DHCP server. Is it possible to for example setup secondary DHCP server which would only provide the missing option to PXE clients? Iam opened to any other solution, just please, keep in mind, that I need this current DHCP to stay.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found this, so it is possible:

http://danielboca.blogspot.cz/2012/02/boot-linux-from-network-using-pxe-and.html

The part with DNSMASQ is important

Comment: what you really need is a proxyDHCP

Answer (score -3):

In general; no. You're only meant to have one "authoritative" DHCP server per subnet. This is because the client broadcasts a "who am I?" request without knowing who/where the DHCP server is; and the DHCP server is meant to notice this, allocate an IP address from the pool and respond with a "You are ...." reply - if there are 2 DHCP servers they both reply and the client gets all confused.

The easiest way out (other than fixing/replacing the existing DHCP server) may be to create a new subnet, such that packets broadcast on the new subnet don't make it to the existing network (but other traffic does). Then you'd assign a range of IP addresses to the new subnet (and make sure those IP addresses can't be assigned by the old DHCP server), and have a new DHCP server managing that pool of IP addresses for the new subnet.

Comment: I have found it... it is possible and I already verified, that it works: http://danielboca.blogspot.cz/2012/02/boot-linux-from-network-using-pxe-and.html

Comment: this answer is wrong, a DHCP Server and a proxyDHCP server can perfectly coexist w/o any problem within the same MAC broadcast domain .

Comment: @Pat: Only one can be "authoritative".

Comment: please read what a proxyDHCP does.

Comment: @Pat: It's a hideous hack that fails to comply with any of the official DHCP protocol standards and needs special non-standard support in the client just to work in the first place.

Comment: You are wrong; The proxyDHCP protocol is an integral part of the PXE standard v2.1 and for that reason it must be implemented in every NIC supporting PXE. Please do not cast these kind of statements if you refuse to read the corresponding standards.