# Install Linux (lubuntu) from an other then the boot medium

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console, installation

I have a big problem to install Lubuntu on an old laptop.
The thing is, I can boot from CD only and start live mode. That works.
But I can't install because the CD-Drive is really buggy. I have the same iso on a usb-stick, which I created via Universal-USB-Installer. So question is, how can I start the install from the usb-stick using the lubuntu-live I run from CD?

Answer (score 0):

Simply mount the iso to a folder and run the installer in that folder. Linux will not see a difference between a mounted iso file and a mounted CD drive.

The command to mount an iso looks something like this:

```
mount -o loop disk.iso /mnt/disk
```

Make sure you create the folder /mnt/disk first.

Comment: and what file do I have to run? I mean its nice to see the img but how can I start the install process?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my answer. I just tried this with Ubuntu and I can't get it to work either (it does work with other distributions and I believe I did something similar with older versions of Ubuntu). Your best bet is probably booting from the USB (without the CD). There are various guides for this on the Ubuntu website. You may have to check your BIOS to change the order of boot devices.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: and thats the problem ... it doesnt boot from usb!

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting to try out Lubuntu with an older Motion PC LE1600 tablet PC which has a USB port.

I created a bootable USB drive with the Universal USB installer and Lubuntu 14.04.1 using a Windows 8 PC.

Then I tried using the bootable USB with the LE1600 tablet and could not make it work.

There were provisions to boot from the hard disk, Windows XP, or from a CD or from a network.  Nothing about a USB and every time I chose local drive, it just booted from the hard disk into Windows XP.

However since I had Windows XP, I looked on the USB drive and there was an application called wubi.exe on the drive with the other stuff so I just double clicked it to see what would happen.

Here is some info about [wubi.exe and it seems to be something available with Lubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards).  The wubi.exe application takes a long time, about 20 minutes on the LE1600 tablet, however at the end I was able to boot up with either Windows XP or Lubuntu.

What wubi.exe seems to do is to add the capability to do a dual boot as now the LE1600 starts up and has two options, Windows XP or Lubuntu.

When I choose Lubuntu, it starts right up and seems to run from the USB drive.  There is an option to perform a full install from Lubuntu.

This may work for you as well.

By the way I found that the stylus was supported on the LE1600 with Lubuntu 14.04 acting like a mouse.

Another possibility is to use a USB connected DVD/CD drive.  I have used that in the past successfully to boot from a CD and do an install.  However it will depend on whether the BIOS supports it or not.

Comment: Maybe that would help, but there is no OS on the laptop. Its a clean formated drive and because the cd-drive is nearly dead no chance to get windows installed.

Comment: Does your lap top allow booting from a USB drive? Another alternative would be to setup a PXE network boot server.  Here is a starting place for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933521/how-to-setup-pxe-on-separate-dhcp-server and this web site article describes the PXE concept http://networkboot.org/fundamentals/

Comment: also doing a bit of reading I came across this http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html which seems to have worked for people who did not have USB boot support on their device.  I suppose the problem is getting the boot loader onto the disk in the first place though and looking through the documentation, it looks like it would work with PXE and there is some information about how to setup a PXE server.

Comment: Another possibility is to remove the drive from the lap top and put it into a computer that does have a functioning CD drive or does support boot from a USB drive and to then use the wubi.exe to create the boot manager on the hard disk.  Then just move the hard disk back to the laptop and try it out.  I think at that point you would be able to boot from the USB drive using the boot manager that comes with wubi.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Unetbootin. It will copy the files from the iso to the usb and make it bootable. After boot, try out the live version and decide if you want a full install.

Comment: Like I sad before, the laptop  is to old and not able to boot from USB. So there can't be a solution which uses a USB-Boot drive/stick